# Cloud storage region for BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I want to set up access and usage logging for Google Cloud Storage bucket. That bucket is of **Multi-Regional** storage class and **European Union** location.

For logs storage I need to create another GCS bucket. Later I'm going to analyze logs data with BigQuery. I'm going to use **Nearline** storage class for the logs bucket, since I'm not going to access that data frequently and to reduce costs. But I'm not sure about bucket's location.

Does bucket location matter for access and storage logging and loading data to BigQuery for the point of view of extra charges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading and exporting data are free, regardless of the bucket location or storage class. see the [Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing) page for details.